# Mysql slow after a while until reboot

Tags: mysql, performance, mariadb

Mysql became slow after a while until I reboot, it's fast again, then gets slow after a while.

This started after I accidentally deleted everything in `/var/log`.
Mysql and mariadb wouldn't start at all after that but I managed to recreate some of the logs and it works but it gets slow after a while.

Comment: Is it slow for reading, writing or both? Are you regularly running any kind of logical backup (mysqldump, mydumper, ...)? (This can "pollute" the memory pools.) Is this on a dedicated MariaDB server? Which version of MariaDB? Which storage engine(s) are you using? (InnoDB, MyISAM, Aria, something else?)

Comment: Do you have indexes?  Have you identified which queries are slow?  Is the slowlog turned on?

Comment: Additional information request. Post on pastebin.com and share the links.
RAM size of your MySQL Host server 
Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
E) complete MySQLTuner report if readily available - 7 or more days uptime is helpful
AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes - 
htop OR top OR mytop for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a linux/unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis.